# Using if statement for a null variable which is not running correctly

Tags: php

I have a variable which its value is NULL I am trying to only show a button if their ID doesn't match a variable or if the variable is not null, here's my script:

```
<?php if($this->id != Session::get('id') || $this->id != NULL): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>messages/compose/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-envelope-alt"></i>Send message</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

No matter what, the href is still being shown, I have tried `is_null`, `empty`, `!isset()`, I `var_dump` the variable, which comes back with `NULL` hence it shouldn't show the a href, but low and behold it's still showing it.

Comment: Please post a var_dump of the involved variables: var_dump($this->id), var_dump (Session::get())

Comment: I did, it returned NULL, hence why I am so confused with my if statement.

Comment: I think your second unequals condition is wrong. Try it this way: if($this->id != Session.. || $this->id == NULL). So it matches if id differs from Session or id is null.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to only show the href if $this->id is anything but NULL.

Comment: @randommman `null` for what? Matthias asked you to show the values for two variables

Comment: @phil The first query is correct, it's the latter one, I have tested the first if statement and that's working, it's just the 2nd one that isn't working, and the $this->id returns null, and my latter statement needs to be if $this->id is anything but null then show href

Comment: Please explain in simple terms, what exactly are the conditions that should result in the link showing. Right now it looks like this... *"show link if `$this->id` is not equal to `Session::get('id')` **or** `$this->id` is not null"*. Also provide values for **both** `$this->id` and `Session::get('id')` where you are not seeing what you expect

Comment: If `$this->id` is `null`, then it must be your first condition that is returning *truthy*, that being *"`$this->id` **is not equal to** `Session::get('id')`"*

Comment: var_dump for Session:get('id') = string(1) "3" and the var_dump of $this->id = NULL

I want to show the link if $this->id doesn't match session id or if $this->id not empty/null

Comment: @randommman and that's exactly what you're doing. I think you want to use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Your logic seems wrong since this statement can **never** evaluate to false.

Comment: lol thanks phil.. my defense it's 3am.

Comment: Maybe something like this : _<?php if($this->id != NULL &&  $this->id != Session::get('id')): ?>_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using `&&` instead of `||`

```
<?php if($this->id != Session::get('id') && $this->id != NULL): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>messages/compose/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-envelope-alt"></i>Send message</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't want to accept a short answer so here's some information about `AND` and `OR` statements

**AND and OR operator**

> The AND operator displays a record if both the first condition AND the
>   second condition are true.
>
> The OR operator displays a record if either the first condition OR the
>   second condition is true.

**AND operator example**

> The following SQL statement selects all customers from the country
>   "Germany" AND the city "Berlin", in the "Customers" table:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND City='Berlin';
```

**OR operator example**

> The following SQL statement selects all customers from the city
>   "Berlin" OR "München", in the "Customers" table:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City='Berlin'
OR City='München';
```

**Combining AND and OR statements**

> You can also combine AND and OR (use parenthesis to form complex
>   expressions).
>
> The following SQL statement selects all customers from the country
>   "Germany" AND the city must be equal to "Berlin" OR "München", in the
>   "Customers" table:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE Country='Germany'
    AND (City='Berlin' OR City='München');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the and not the or

```
<?php if($this->id != Session::get('id') && $this->id != NULL): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>messages/compose/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-envelope-alt"></i>Send message</a>
```